# Are there any info or links that clearly covers paypal integration in react native?

Tags: react-native, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I would like to setup a paypal payment method exactly the same as Airbnb. The payment will be recurring on a monthly basis.

Comment: AirBnB uses billing agreements to make reference transactions for arbitrary amounts and does not bill monthly, which is different from a regular monthly recurrence, and completely different if that regular monthly recurrence is for a fixed cost that the user agreed to during signup, so you will need to be more specific about what you are asking about.

Answer (score -1):

If one user is directly paying another user for a fixed amount that recurs automatically every month between just their accounts (very different from AirBnB's setup), that can be done with a Subscribe button. The easiest integration will be to create a classic HTML-only Subscribe button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons , uncheck the option in Step 2 to save the button at PayPal, and once the code is generated click the link to remove code protection. This will give you a button with variables you can adjust, per [HTML Variable for Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), including the `business` destination in particular.

Newer [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) can be used instead, but are more complex to set up, as each user will need to have the appropriate recurring Plan created for them via an API call, and you will need their Client ID and Secret to do that from your server.

Since you are using React Native, it is important to note that all PayPal flows [require a web interface](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/) that includes an address bar, such as Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tab. A WKWebView or similar cannot be used.